# TCL Idol X (s950) stuck in bootloop, after flashing new firmware

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, unbricking, device-firmware

I have flashed new firmware on my phone TCL Idol X (s950) and now the phone won't boot anymore :(

- It starts but then it ends up with the bootlogo.
- I can access it with `adb shell` but it is read only mode.
- Switch it off reboot the phone.
- Recovery doesn't start.

How can I rescue it from the bootloop or get into recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

- **Connect the phone to the charger**
- Switch it off (10 sec press power button)
- As soon as the led light up and the phone screen is black, disconnect it from the charger
- The phone should remain off ( wait for 10 sec to be sure )
- Connect again the charger and then unplug it after 5 sec
- Now try to boot the recovery (`power + volume up` )

Once you are in recovery:

- fix the permission to enable `r/w` on system.
- Clean Cache and Dalvin Cache
- if you need flash it again ( you can push file with `adb` )

Now the phone boots perfectly! I'm using [lewa mod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2350202) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I start flashtool on pc, choose scatter file, disabled preeloader, mobileinfo and userdatam, then press download

I take my phone in one hand and usb cable in another. 
press power button until screen is off and immediately insert usb cable. SPFlashtool will start the process.